# Changes in XCode App Delegate don't show up in simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, uiapplicationdelegate

This is really bugging me to the point where I'm going to have to step away for a bit.

So I am coding away and decide to change which ViewController gets launched on startup.  I go into the app delegate and make the changes so that the the new ViewController will get loaded on startup, but when I run it in the simulator, the old one appears.

I've cleaned out the simulator, and i've tried "touching" files to force a relinking of the resources and it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I can get an error to happen when I change the name of the ViewController in the app delegate to something like "vc".  I then get a linking error saying the key value pair isn't found.

Anyways, if I am trying to just change which viewcontroller starts up in the app delegate, is there anything other than coding changes that I need to look at to inform xcode that I'm doing this?  I've been searching google and working on this for the last couple hours and not really making any progress.  If it makes any difference, this is for an ipad app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you connect the controller IBOutlet of the app delegate with the your view controller?
Check your main XIB file in InterfaceBuilder. 
And of course don't forget to save your changes made in InterfaceBuilder before launching the app since there is no "auto-save".

Comment: That was it.  Thanks. I feel dumb.  I forgot all about that relation.  Thanks a bunch!